# subshell and Input/Output Redirections questions

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, io

I have a couple of questions about the behavior of the shell i/o

```
echo apple | echo banana
```

The output here is only

```
banana
```

But in this command:

```
echo apple | { echo banana; tail; }
```

the output is

```
banana
apple
```

Why does banana appear before apple?
And why does apple appear unlike the first command, what's happening?

```
echo apple | { echo banana; rev; }
```

The output of the command above is

```
banana
elppa
```

how come apple gets revesed and not banana?
is it because `echo banana; rev;` is being executed at the same time?

```
echo apple >&2 | { echo banana; rev; }
```

the output of the command above :

```
banana
apple
```

This makes sense for me in comparison with the command before, since we make apple go to the error output and `rev` only takes standard output.

```
echo apple >&2 | { echo banana; rev; } | tac
```

output:

```
apple
banana
```

I'm not sure why `tac` reversed the order of lines, does it take in consideration the error output too?

```
{ echo apple >&2; echo banana; } | rev | tac
```

output:

```
apple
ananab
```

I think here that apple did'nt get `rev` since it's error output and banana did, but again why does `tac` behave this way

Comment: A few facts may help you understand: (1) Commands in a pipeline are launched in parallel (2) The `echo` builtin ignores input (3) `echo banana; rev` does not send *banana* to `rev`'s input (4) `tac` did not take *apple* as input and therefore did not reverse the lines. The lines are reversed because the various `echo`'s run in parallel.

Comment: It is said elsewhere that braces don't launch subshells; you'd use parentheses for that.